# What is the difference between % and vw in css?

Tags: css, user-interface, width, sizing

1vw = 1%, so if they are 100% interchangeable why they both exist? I feel % depends on the size of wrapper tag but vh is always dependent on window size no matter of size of wrapper tag. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They aren't necessarily interchangeable.

The behavior will mainly depend on the element's position in the DOM, since this will determine what the element's containing block is. If an element has a width of `100%`, it will have a width of `100%` of the containing block's **width**. If the element has a width of `100vw`, it will have a width of `100%` of the viewport's **width** (the viewport may not be the element's containing element, but viewport-percentage units will always be relative to the viewport).

A strictly percentage based width will always be relative to another element's width, but when using viewport-percentage lengths, an element's width can actually be relative to the viewport's height. For instance, if an element has a width of `100vh`, it will have a width of `100%` of the viewport's **height**. This isn't possible when using strictly percentage based widths.

Viewport-percentage length are always going to be relative to their [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details), which is the viewport:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details). When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

Whereas percentage based units are going to be relative to their parent element (i.e., their containing block), which may happen to be the `body`/`html` element, in which case they will be similar to viewport-percentage lengths.

> [**4.3. Percentages: the ‘`<percentage>`’ type**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#percentages)
>
> Percentage values are always relative to another value, for example a length. Each property that allows percentages also defines the value to which the percentage refers. The value may be that of another property for the same element, a property for an ancestor element, or a value of the formatting context (e.g., the width of a containing block). When a percentage value is set for a property of the root element and the percentage is defined as referring to the inherited value of some property, the resultant value is the percentage times the initial value of that property.

Comment: Also `vw` does not take the scroll bar into account if you have `overflow: auto;` for your `html`/`body` tag which is the default. So if you have a vertical scroll bar due to the length of your content and then make _any_ element `width: 100vw;` and, you will get a horizontal scroll bar which sucks.